# Flot: toggle data series by clicking legend & curvedLines plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I have a problem with flot curvedLines plugin. I toggle data series by clicking on legend but if curvedLines plugin is active I have some problem. I try to deactivate the plugin all work. I don't know if there are some error in my code o is a plugin problem. Can you help me? This is my code:

```
        $(function() {

        somePlot = null;            
        togglePlot = function(seriesIdx)
        {
          var someData = somePlot.getData();                  
          someData[seriesIdx].lines.show = !someData[seriesIdx].lines.show;               
          somePlot.setData(someData);
          somePlot.draw();
        }
            var d1 = {{ d1|safe }}
            var d2 = {{ d2|safe }}
            var d3 = {{ d3|safe }}      
            var dataset = [{ label: "Data1", 
                            data: d1, 
                            lines : {show : true, lineWidth : 3, fill:true},                                
                            //curvedLines: {apply: true,fit : true},
                            color: "#5482FF",   
                            idx: 0,                                                         
                            },
                            { label: "Data2", 
                            data: d2, 
                            lines : {show : true, lineWidth : 3, fill:true},                                
                            //curvedLines: {apply: true,fit : true},
                            color: "#ed4e2a",
                            idx: 1,
                            },
                { data: d1,
                points : {show : true, radius: 0.5}},
                { data: d2,
                points : {show : true, radius: 0.5}},
                            ];      
            var options = {
                series : {
                    curvedLines : {active : true},
                    stack: true,
                },
                legend: {
                    noColumns: 0,
                    labelBoxBorderColor: "#000000",
                    position: "nw",
                    labelFormatter: function(label, series){
                            return '<input type="checkbox" name="data" checked="checked" id="iddata" onClick="togglePlot('+series.idx+'); return false;">'+label;                               
                            }
                    },
                grid: {hoverable: true,clickable: true,mouseActiveRadius: 30,},
                xaxis:{mode: "time"}, 
            };

            somePlot = $.plot($("#flotFit"),dataset, options);
            $("#flotFit").UseTooltip();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Please reproduce your problem.  I've attempted to here and see no issues: http://plnkr.co/edit/3rS8Kr89PDyUD7L1qVm6?p=preview.  One thing to note is that you are configuring two series for each of your datasets, one show lines, the other points.  I wasnt sure if this was on purpose.

Comment: @Mark the problem was in the plugin. I put in my code the same of the example and all works well! Thanks a lot.